# VBA cannot debug code after pasting range with formatConditions

Tags: vba, excel

I know there are ways to get around the following problem, but I am still curious:
I have a macro which pastes ranges between different workbooks. One of those ranges that gets copied to another workbook contains a few cells with conditional formats. After I paste this range to another workbook, excel stops working and crashes if I try to debug the code (by adding a line with 'Stop' or any other methods) until the workbook I pasted it to gets closed by the code.

So for example this would cause excel to crash:

```
'Assume the sourceRange contains the cells with conditionalFormats
sourceFile.Sheets(sourceSheetName).Range(sourceRangeAddress).Copy
targetFile.Sheets(targetSheetName).Range(targetPasteAddress).PasteSpecial xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats
Stop
```

I have already tried different types of paste special and also the .copy destination:=... method.
Using a breakpoint instead of STOP leads to the same result.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Does the same happen if you copy/paste manually? Is it possible that some kind of event routine in the target wb is triggered?

Comment: I also tried it with disabling events before and enabling them afterwards, same result. If i do it manually everything is fine. The copy/paste code is also working fine, i just cant do any debugging after these line were executed.

Comment: *"Cant do any debugging"* is something different than *"Excel crashes"*. What exactly is the behaviour?

Comment: @FunThomas When the code reaches a breakpoint, the VBA editor window pops up, then the usual 'Excel has stopped working, searching for a solution..' window pops up and all open excel related windows close.

Comment: @FunThomas If i set a breakpoint before the lines that do the copy and pasting, I can do step by step debugging through the entire code without a problem though. I just cant do it if the breakpoint is reached after the copy and pasting is done.

Comment: Hmm, no clue. One of the mysterios things with Excel. Have you checked if the code after the Paste is executed (put a `Debug.print` after the `paste`)

Comment: Yes, everything works as intended. It only crashes if I set and reach a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

please replace:

```
sourceFile.Sheets(sourceSheetName).Range(sourceRangeAddress).Copy
targetFile.Sheets(targetSheetName).Range(targetPasteAddress).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats
```

Comment: What i already posted is everything that is relevant, the entire code is to long to post.  I am not looking for a fix, just for a possible explanation.